# Display font size on a webpage

Tags: html, jquery

I have a webpage that allows visitors to change the font size on the page using a Jquery script. The resize script works fine, however I need it to display the size that the font is on the page. Document.write does not seem to work or I am doing it wrong.
This is what I have tried

```js
document.querySelector('.results');
$('.results').html(fontSize);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var fontSize;
  $("#insize").click(function() {
    fontSize = parseInt($("p").css('font-size'));
    fontSize = fontSize + 3 + "px";
    $("p").css({
      'font-size': fontSize
    });
  });
  $("#desize").click(function() {
    fontSize = parseInt($("p").css('font-size'));
    fontSize = fontSize - 3 + "px";
    $("p").css({
      'font-size': fontSize
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="desize">increase font</a>
<a href="#" id="insize">decrease font</a>
<p class="results">results</p>
```

That did not work, I got and undefined result. So next, I tried this

```js
var fontSize;
$("#insize").click(function() {
  fontSize = parseInt($("p").css('font-size'));
  fontSize = fontSize + 3 + "px";
  $("p").css({
    'font-size': fontSize
  });
  $("#fsize").document.write(fsize);
})
```

```html
<p id="fsize"></p>
```

This didn’t work either, I tried a bunch of other methods, it seems to me that it is possible to display a declared var, but not possible to get the current fontsize of the text on the webpage, by the way it’s only the `<p>` element I am concerned with since the `<h1>` and other elements have different font size values.

How can I display the current font size on the screen without writing miles of code to accomplish it? Can it be done with a simple E.G. `$("#fsize").write("p");`?

Comment: It seems like you have a typeerror in `<a href="#" id="desize">increase font</a>
` your increase font have the id `desize` and like goes for the decrese font

Comment: You're looking for `.text()` -> `$("#fsize").text(fsize)`  https://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: @freedomn-m - You're right - one reason why I hate jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempt to use document.write can be replaced with .text()

```
$("#fsize").document.write(fsize);
```

becomes

```
$("#fsize").text(fsize);
```

Your first attempt `.html(fsize)` would also have worked if it was inside the event handler.

Updated code (with increase/decrease around the correct way as well):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var fontSize;
  $("#insize").click(function() {
    fontSize = parseInt($("p").css('font-size'));
    fontSize = fontSize + 3 + "px";
    $("p").css({
      'font-size': fontSize
    });
    
    $(".results").text("font size: " + fontSize);
    
  });
  $("#desize").click(function() {
    fontSize = parseInt($("p").css('font-size'));
    fontSize = fontSize - 3 + "px";
    $("p").css({
      'font-size': fontSize
    });
    
    $(".results").text("font size: " + fontSize);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="insize">increase font</a>
<a href="#" id="desize">decrease font</a>
<p class="results">results</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Change position you var `var fontSize;`

```js
var fontSize ;
document.querySelector('.results');


$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#insize").click(function() {
    fontSize = parseInt($("p").css('font-size'));
    fontSize = fontSize + 3 + "px";
    $("p").css({
      'font-size': fontSize
    });
    $('.results').html(fontSize);
  });
  $("#desize").click(function() {
    fontSize = parseInt($("p").css('font-size'));
    fontSize = fontSize - 3 + "px";
    $("p").css({
      'font-size': fontSize
    });
    $('.results').html(fontSize);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="desize">increase font</a>
<a href="#" id="insize">decrease font</a>

<p class="results">results</p>
```

Comment: This doesn’t **display** the font size

Comment: This removes the script error, but that was just an artifact of converting to a snippet